# Nginx Rewrite Rules - All Sub Folders

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I am migrating site and bringing all my product urls to top level.

Example:

Old URL:  http://www.example.com/sub/folder/product.asp
Old URL:  http://www.example.com/sub1/folder1/product.asp

New URL:  http://www.example.com/product.asp

I am struggling to get the nginx rewrite rule to work how i need it.  Basically anything that ends in *.asp need to strip out all the folder paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to identify URIs ending with `.asp` that include more than one `/`. One possible solution might be:

```
rewrite ^/.+(/[^/]+\.asp)$ $1 permanent;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Comment: That was it.... second backslash I was missing.  perfect thank you  (sorry cant upvote it due to not enough rep yet!)

Comment: As I am using this to reduce the number of redirect rules, ie I have the same product in 7 categories, so instead of adding 7 redirects, this one brings it to root and then I have just 1 redirect to the actual new product location.  ie product1a.html.  What I have now is a 2 hop redirect one in nginx and the second in magento.  Is there a way I can make the nginx one server side redirect so it does not output a response header and just redirects internally?

Comment: You can change the rewrite into an internal redirect by deleting the `permanent` suffix. However, it's very possible that Magento will not recognize an internal redirect.